# Profile2 and Panels in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, panels

How can I override a [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) profile page using [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) in Drupal 7?

The page I'm looking to override is the edit for for one of the new profile2 pages.  Here is an example URL: http://example.com/profile-user_settings/%uid/edit

Comment: What type of override you are looking?

Comment: I want to split the page into two columns.  Left being the original content from the Profile2 edit form, right being a rendered node.  Very easy to do with panels, but can't seem to snag the edit form for use.

Comment: I just thought to look at the Profile2 bugs.  Seems there are a bunch of issues with ctools.  http://drupal.org/project/issues/profile2?text=ctools&status=All  I may have put this up on SA too quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a work around using Page Manager Existing Pages (as [suggested by](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33530/1747) [Letharion](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1625/letharion)) and [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7)().

hook_menu() was required as Profile2 doesn't seem to register profile pages with the menu router. This was preventing Page Manager Existing Pages from being able to intercept the page.

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
    $items['profile-example'] = array(
        'page callback' => '_profile2_form',
        'page arguments' => array(),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );
    return $items;
}

function _profile2_form() {
    global $user;
    module_load_include('inc', 'profile2_page', 'profile2_page');
    $profile2 = profile2_by_uid_load($user->uid, 'profile2_profile_system_name_goes_here');
    $entity_form = entity_ui_get_form('profile2', $profile2, 'edit');
    return $entity_form;    
}
```

This can now be intercepted by [Page Manager Existing Pages](http://drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages) and properly displayed by the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module.

Answer (score 0):

You can plan it with blocks using [Node Block](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock) module that would help to bring any node content to configurable block for profile page.

You can also focus page-profile.tpl.php, if you are looking customization on that page regarding layout. e.g. new region placement etc.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at this, but a guess says that Profile2 will need to implement a ctools "task" for the form to become accessible like other things in the Panels UI.

In your simple use case though, you could try [Page manager existing pages](http://drupal.org/project/pm_existing_pages) which will wrap an existing page for you. This should be enough for your current use case.

Comment: Couldn't get PMEP to get in early enough to grab that pre-existing URL.  Will read through the docs and give it another go though.

Comment: Looked into this a bit more, it seems that PMEP doesn't implement hook_menu().  I'm guessing this is why there is no menu item for PMEP to hijack.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](http://drupal.org/node/1306146) it seems with Panels2.  Overrides can still be done with the default Drupal template engine.

Comment: There is a patch here to provide the missing glue between Panels and Profile2
https://drupal.org/node/1011370#comment-6884220

Answer (score 0):

Responding to Citricguy above, I tried a number of iterations of your great tip, but what finally worked was to, effectively, hardcode the profile2 path for each profile in our system.  Ex:

```
$items['user/%user/edit/consumer_profile'] = array(
  'page callback' => '_profile2_form',
  'page arguments' => array(),
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'title' => 'My Profile',
  'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
);
return $items;
```

The rest of your example remained true. That said, I can probably pass in the "consumer_profile" bit to your entity fetcher helper.

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch here to provide the missing glue between Panels and Profile2.

https://drupal.org/node/1011370#comment-6884220

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "workaround using Page Manager Existing Pages", I assume you wouldn't want `'access callback' => TRUE,` in your menu hook since anonymous users (i.e. uid = 0) wouldn't have a profile and this would result in downstream errors. I suppose you can just add

> 'access arguments' => array('edit own main profile'),

to the array instead to mimic pre-existing permissions for Profile2.