# Different user form for registration and edit

Tags: users, forms

I'm trying to make different forms layout for user registration and user edit account:
- User Registration: Display it paginated, like a wizard.
- User edit: Display it in only one page.

I can use FieldGroup Multipage field to make a paginated user registration form. But it affects the edit page too.

There's some module that can accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[the multistep registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step) module will help you with this I think.
Together with the [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module.
Those 2 modules will help you with the multi step registration part. For the user edit page you should check the checkbox in the profile2 preferences where it says use a seperate page for editting user profiles

Comment: quote "For the user edit page you should check the checkbox...." I would like to know how to create an alternative page using Panel Pages /user/edit) without the 'Tick option' above, I've be trying by 'trial and error' for over 4 hours today and the same yesterday! LOL What is the special knack to do a custom page in instead of the above? Does it need special Contexts?

Comment: This will help you http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33495/profile2-and-panels-in-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks @Akko! Multistep solved the steps for registration. Also added "Page Manager Existing Pages" to make changes for  Edit and Registration page!